# Android Security concerns saving contents in internal storage(storage/emulated/0)

Tags: android, react-native

I was fiddling around with react-native-fs so that users can upload and save images in my app.

I was trying to save images in phone's internal storage, located in '/storage/emulated/0/MyApp', like many other apps do

Using RNFS.readDir('/storage/emulated/0'), I can seem to read the list of all the directories and files here made by other apps also, like personal images and files that I have accessed/downloaded in big apps like telegram, instagram, etc.(e.g. I can access /storage/emulated/0/Telegram/Telegram Images from my app)

Isn't this dangerous? this means that if I wanted to, I can move or upload files(of other apps) of users who are using my app or vice versa, third-party apps can access my private files?

Or am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: Thats why you should not always accept all permissions for every app. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: writing/reading permission can be inevitable for apps if you want to upload images.

I'm just wondering because big companies like telegram, instagram would have definitely taken security concerns like this, so i guess it would be safe to save images in /storage/emulated/0, but I want to be sure